# POI is adding cell background only for first 50 rows

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have previously generated .xls (by Apache POI too), opened again and changing background color by cell value. Problem is, that background is changed not at all cells, but only in first roughly 50 rows, other remains with white bg. Function `mark()` in one for cycle, I tried to dump values, row numbers, tried on the end iterate xls again and again assing color and nothing works...

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;

public class Xls {

   private FileOutputStream fileOut;
   private Sheet xlsSheet;
   private HSSFWorkbook xlsWorkbook;
   private CellStyle cellStyle;

   public Xls(String path) {
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        this.xlsWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        this.xlsSheet = xlsWorkbook.createSheet("test");

        cellStyle = this.xlsWorkbook.createCellStyle();

        Row row1 = xlsSheet.createRow((int) 0);

        this.xlsSheet.autoSizeColumn(0, true);
        this.xlsSheet.autoSizeColumn(1, true);
        this.xlsSheet.autoSizeColumn(2, true);
        this.xlsSheet.autoSizeColumn(3, true);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void mark(int rowNumber, String status) {
        short color = Constants.getColor(status);

        CellStyle style = this.xlsWorkbook.createCellStyle();

        style.setFillForegroundColor(color);
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        //TODO!!! Why filling color only in first 50 rows?!
//            System.out.println("Changing row " + sameRows.get(rowNumber) + " status is:'" + status + "' color:" + color);
            Row row = xlsSheet.getRow(sameRows.get(rowNumber));
            Cell statusCell = null;
            if (!isCellEmpty(row.getCell(3))) {
                statusCell = row.getCell(3);
            } else {
                statusCell = row.createCell(3);
            }

            statusCell.setCellValue(status);
            statusCell.setCellStyle(style);
        }
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea where can be mistake?
NOTE: `setCellValue()` is working - all fields have proper values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CellStyles should not be re-created for every Cell, they are a limited resource in an Excel file (limit is imposed by Excel itself), so rather create the style object only once and re-use it for all cells that should have the same style.

Comment: Thanks, I have more colors so I created few variables and its working ;-)